# Windows 8 store apps read smart card

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PInvoke in Metro Apps with Windows 8 / WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881335/pinvoke-in-metro-apps-with-windows-8-winrt)

Is it possible to use pinvoke.net with Windows 8 and Windows 8 RT?

Something like `[DllImport(" winscard.dll ")]`?

I know it is possible with Windows desktop application, but how about the Windows 8 store app, especially for Windows RT?